# optimizing deletion of data array at fix indexes

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Suppose I have an array of length `N` and I want to delete data at index multiple of `n`, so `0, n, 2n,...`. Of course I can loop through `ArrayUtils.removeElement` but is there an efficient way to do that ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "remove" - arrays are fixed length. Are you wanting a new, shorter array, or are you wanting to shuffle the elements left and pad the end with a particular value?

Comment: Also: `n-1`, `2n-1` etc aren't multiples of `n`, but `0` is. What is the removal pattern you are looking for?

Comment: @AndyTurner oups sorry typo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

- calculate the length of the new array.
- copy the portions with System.arrayCopy. e.g. n+1 to 2n-1.